# While loop printing line incorrectly

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class US_Defense {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" ------------------------------------- ");
        System.out.println("  Welcome to the U.S. Defense Network  ");
        System.out.println(" ------------------------------------- ");
        System.out.println("   Please Input your password below.   ");
        System.out.println(" ------------------------------------- ");  


        String pass = "";
        while(!pass.equals("0286139") ){
            System.out.println(" ------------------------------------- ");
            System.out.println("     Incorrect password. Try again.    ");
            System.out.println(" ------------------------------------- ");

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("  >: ");
            pass = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click run it says the welcome and enter password part, but then it says incorrect password and the user input prompt. I'm trying to have so the code only says welcome and input password but its not doing that.

Comment: Move the `Scanner` out of the loop so it doesn't get recreated every time. Then ask for input before the loop

Comment: `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); String pass = in.nextLine(); //your while loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `do-while` loop is probably the cleanest solution. It's a good idea to flush `System.out` when you `print` (if you don't include a new-line there isn't an implicit flush). If you really want a `while` loop you can use the fact that assignment resolves to the right-hand side like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("  >: ");
System.out.flush();
String pass;
while (!(pass = input.nextLine()).equals("0286139")) {
    System.out.println(" ------------------------------------- ");
    System.out.println("     Incorrect password. Try again.    ");
    System.out.println(" ------------------------------------- ");

    System.out.print("  >: ");
    System.out.flush();
}
```

But, a `do-while` (as mentioned) would be cleaner, and might look like

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.print("  >: ");
    System.out.flush();
    String pass = input.nextLine();
    if (pass.equals("0286139")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(" ------------------------------------- ");
    System.out.println("     Incorrect password. Try again.    ");
    System.out.println(" ------------------------------------- ");
} while (true);
```